# disk io error on a group by sql statement on a esp32 running sqlite

Tags: sqlite, group-by, esp32, sd-card

i am running a sqlite database on an esp32 with a sdcard and its running fine. no problems until i use the 'group by clause' in a statement, its returning error code 10 disk io error.
after searching the internet i came to the conclusion that it has to do with the journal file. i have manulay created one but no succes. help much appreciated.

running the group by sql statement on the sdcard connected to the pc works fine so i suspect the esp32 sd sqlite software combination is somehow the problem.

thanx in advance
Ed

Comment: Are you sure SQLite can write to the esp32? Is there sufficient available space left for the journal file? Disk I/O error is vague, it can mean different things.

Comment: yes its running perfect except for that particular statement. I am now running the web version of sqlite3 but no progress

Comment: Hi Ed, how about posting a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - there's not really much we can do to help you without any code.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3.c

```
static int vdbeSorterOpenTempFile(...

rc = sqlite3OsOpenMalloc(db->pVfs, 0, ppFd,
                             SQLITE_OPEN_TEMP_JOURNAL |
                             SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE |
                             SQLITE_OPEN_EXCLUSIVE | SQLITE_OPEN_DELETEONCLOSE, &rc);
```

I think '0' cause this error. Try to put temporary filename instead of '0'.